# help on install ROS in a MacBook with OSX 10.6.6

Tags: rosinstall, macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS in my MacBook OSX 10.6.6.

after doing the command:
rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=ros-full&overlay=no"

that appears in "http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/OSX".

I got this output, can anyone give a hint how to solve this issue?
...

```
Bootstrapping ROS build
Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 60, in <module>
    from ros import rosmake
  File "/Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    import roslib
  File "/Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
  File "/Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/launcher.py", line 45, in <module>
    import roslib.manifest
  File "/Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/manifest.py", line 46, in <module>
    import roslib.packages
  File "/Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/packages.py", line 58, in <module>
    import roslib.os_detect
  File "/Users/paulogoncalves/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 49, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.16', 'rosinstall')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 442, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1167, in run_script
    exec script_code in namespace, namespace
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 556, in <module>
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 547, in rosinstall_main
    
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 462, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/paulogoncalves/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

thx,
Paulo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9434/help-on-install-ros-in-a--macbook-with-osx-10.6.6/) by [paulo](https://answers.ros.org/users/296/paulo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means that the YAML module for Python was not installed.  Are you sure you ran these steps:

{{{
sudo port install wget cmake python_select subversion mercurial
sudo python_select python26
sudo easy_install -U pyyaml
}}}

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on 2011-03-17**:
I had a similar problem http://answers.ros.org/question/385/problem-with-mac-os-installation-with-yaml. I think what I explained over there is pretty much what one needs to do, since I installed ROS on a fresh install of OS X.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-16**:
I've changed the instructions to use py26-yaml instead.  We probably need better instructions for getting easy_install itself.  My machine is too contaminated to validate proper instructions there.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-16**:
Should this command be added to the wiki instructions?

**Comment by [paulo](https://answers.ros.org/users/296/paulo/) on 2011-03-16**:
in the meanwhile I have written the command: sudo port install py26-yaml   . it is now moving :-)

**Comment by [paulo](https://answers.ros.org/users/296/paulo/) on 2011-03-16**:
yes I have done the steps that you refer. I have done the steps again and not solved the problem. can you help further.